# Airflow: How can I create a virtual python environment in distributed airflow in runtime for a tfx-pipeline using the tfx's AirflowDagRunner?

Tags: tfx, airflow

I have DAGS which I want to run in different python environments in the same distributed airflow cluster. Is it possible to create a virtual python environment while executing the DAG?

I am looking to add tfx ML pipelines to our distributed airflow platform and It is not possible to install tfx individually in the each of the worker nodes.

EDIT: I am looking to use the inherent tfx AirflowDagRunner which is based on python  operators. I would prefer not changing any tfx code to handle the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and tear down virtual environments (`venv`) at will. It would be best if your software was not awaiting results from an environment before it is torn down.

To create an environment programmatically, just run a shell command from your favorite programming language and pass in the usual command line. The venv will be selected if you execute a Python program using the `python` program in the venv.

For example, if you create a venv in `/var/venvs/123`, run your Python program with a command line something like `/var/venvs/123/bin/python`, and pass any parameters necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should try **PythonVirtualenvOperator**, Airflow will create special venv with depedencies from operator parameters

example venv with openpyxl and pandas libraries:

```
extract_some_data = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id="extract_some_data ",
    python_callable=extract_some_data ,
    requirements=["openpyxl", "pandas"],
    python_version='3.7',
    system_site_packages=False,
    provide_context=True,
    op_kwargs={
        "uuid": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='generate_uuid') }}"
    },
    dag=dag
)
```

**Airflow documentation:**

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html?highlight=pythonoperator#airflow.operators.python.PythonOperator

Comment: I would like to do it via ttx's AirflowDagRunner if possible. TFX has an dagrunner which executes each node using AirflowComponents which is a child class of PythonOperator. Do you know how I could use that? Thanks for your help!